# Formatting text with RichtTextBlock

Tags: xaml, mvvm-light, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Small question, anyone have a small example on different data formatting tips when using a RichTextBlock control in Windows8 - XAML?

Currently I'm MVVM binding the Paragraph element of the RichTextBlock to a large text property on my MVVM.

But I was wondering, how can I indicate where to add Line break, setting titles, etc...?
Anyone any good tips on doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never worked with the RichTextBlock before but there's an interesting topic on the MSDN forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/d215abeb-7acd-41c1-81ba-c73a0ab68785 where an MSFT employee explains you should use the [Blocks property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richtextblock.blocks.aspx).

Now, the Blocks property is of type BlockCollection, meaning it can hold any type of block. In your ViewModel you could fill the property with an **HTML** string (containing your text with headers, paragraphs, ...). Then you should consider creating an attached behavior that reads the HTML and creates the required blocks (like **Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents.Paragraph**) to finally fill up the Blocks property.

Take a look at the following guide to create attached behaviors: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/dragflickbehavior-windows

```
<RichTextBlock ...>
    <MyBehaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <MyBehaviors:RichTextBehavior HtmlText="{Binding ...}"/>
    </MyBehaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
</RichTextBlock>
```